# Get the char of a ascii give by a certain position of a string

Tags: c#

i want to get the char of an ascii give by a certain position of a string on c#  but i can't reach te correct way.

Code:

```
string Str;
string StrEnd;
int Clave = 0;

Str = txtStr.Text;
Clave = Convert.ToInt32(txtCv.Text);

for (int i = 0; i == Str.Length - 1; i++)
{
    StrEnd = (char)Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str[index: i]) + Clave;
}
```

For EG.

`Str = "ABC"` , and `var Clave = 1` then `string StrEnd` would look like this `"BCD"`.

other example would be...

`Str = "Hola"`, `Clave  = 2` then `StrEnd = "Jqnc"`

if still not clear, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` converts a string to a number (e.g. "1234" to 1234)

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Can you put some example of input and output you want?

Comment: `StrEnd = (char)Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str[index: i]) + Clave;` what you are trying to achieve here? can you give us some idea

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: @GaurangDave i want to get a new character based on the one i'm stand. this is the result of getting the ascii code of the current char and then adding the var 'Clave', then from that number get the new character. And at the end getting a new string with the original being encrypted.

Comment: This loop condition isn't what you want: `for (int i = 0; i == Str.Length - 1; i++)`. You almost certainly want `for (int i = 0; i < Str.Length; i++)` - or just `foreach (char c in Str)`. But it's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @FacundoLabonia pal, still its not clear. As I said, **can you edit your question and put a sample of input and output?** The code you shared is with error and I think no one is getting what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @GaurangDave i will try to make it more clear

Comment: @GaurangDave OP has edited question, now it is quite clearer

Comment: @Amit Thanks. I submitted my answer. :)

Comment: @FacundoLabonia Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is as below,

```
string Str = txtStr.Text;
string  StrEnd = string.Empty;
int clave = Convert.ToInt32(txtCv.Text);
foreach(char c in Str) 
{
   StrEnd += (char)(c + clave);
}
```

Comment: You can lose the `(int)` casting of `c`, write only `c + clave` and it will work fine

Comment: @SlavenTojić thanks for suggestion! Casting must be handled internally here! it reminds me another suggestion "If something language does internally (it is widely accepted and tested), better to leave it on language rather than creating our own solution for that".

Answer (score 2):

It's missing a Linq solution:
(If the C# version in use doesn't allow an auto [out] parameter, add `int key = 0;`).

```
string Str = "Hola";
if (int.TryParse(txtCv.Text, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out int key))
{
    string StrEnd = string.Join("", Str.Select(c => (char)(c + key)));
}
```

With `key == 2`: `StrEnd = "Jqnc"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution :

```
string StrEnd="";

string Str = txtStr.Text;

int Clave = Convert.ToInt32(txtCv.Text);

for (int i = 0; i < Str.Length; i++)
{
    StrEnd += (char)(Str[i] + Clave);
}
```

Comment: spelling of Length is wrong. I assume you did not test this code.

Comment: And it is not returning any output. Just tested your code and it is returning NOTHING

Answer (score 0):

I tested code on Console Application. Please change it to your needed application. But the logic works as you asked.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Str;
    string StrEnd = string.Empty;
    int Clave = 1;

    Str = "ABC";

    foreach (char c in Str)
    {
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new char[] { c });
        asciiBytes[0] = (byte) (asciiBytes[0] + Clave);
        StrEnd += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(asciiBytes);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(StrEnd);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Summary of this code**

```
Str = "ABC"; Clave = 1; StrEnd="BCD";
```

Comment: thank you Dave, I'm still adapting to c #, is way more tricky than VB 6.0

Comment: @FacundoLabonia You are welcome. Please upvote/mark as answer if it is useful to you.

Comment: @GaurangDave have a look at my answer, It looks quite simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @SlavenTojić once On a great answer on my question (here on SO only) I got a suggestion, "Cleaner code is always better" :)

Comment: @Amit I am agreeing with you :)

Comment: @bommelding Thanks for suggestion. There are many way of doing this. All the answers are working solution and I am sure if someone tries more , will get a new way of achieving this.